# Rust - update tree node with output from children

Tags: dynamic, rust, tree, borrow-checker

I'm trying to implement a **tree** structure where each node is **updated** using some output from its **children**.

The **output can't be cloned or moved** in the final applicaton. I'm running into multiple borrows errors, when I give the node ref's of its children to update it.

I'm using the [indextree](https://crates.io/crates/indextree) crate.

Can't get my head around it... Can't find anything like this with this updating behavior.

my example [code](https://pastebin.com/YpBHSjXi) :

The tree contains dynamic nodes like this

```rust
type NodeOutput = i64; //(Can't be copied) wgpu::TextureView in final version  

trait CalcNode {
    fn update(&mut self, input: Vec<&dyn CalcNode>);
    fn output(&self) -> NodeOutput;
}
 
struct NodeModel {
    output: NodeOutput, // generated output ()
    internal: i64,      // some internal state
}
 
impl CalcNode for NodeModel {
    //input can't be cloned/copied in final version
    fn update(&mut self, input: Vec<&dyn CalcNode>) {
        //example for a possible update function
        let child_input: i64 = input.iter().map(|&f| f.output()).sum();
        self.output = self.internal * child_input;
        self.internal += 1 
        // this is only an simplified example 
        //the final version is rendering to a Texture
    }
 
    fn output(&self) -> NodeOutput {
        // output is not copy-able in final version
        self.output
    }
}
 
impl NodeModel {
    fn new(internal: i64) -> Self {
        Self {
            output: internal,
            internal,
        }
    }
}
```

And then I'm trying to update the tree like this:

```rust
use indextree::{Arena, NodeId};

fn main() {
    let (mut arena_, root) = build_tree(); //generate some Tree
    let arena = &mut arena_;
 

    let node_stack: Vec<NodeId> = root.descendants(arena).collect(); //collect all nodes depth first
 

        //update in reverse order deepest node first, ROOT LAST.
        for &n in node_stack.iter().rev() {

            // collect updated children when available
            let children: Vec<&dyn CalcNode> = {
                n.children(arena)
                    .map(|f| arena.get(f).unwrap().get().as_ref())
                    .collect()
            };
 
            //get the node to update
            //--- can't borrow arena here to get the node ---
            let node = { arena.get_mut(n).unwrap().get_mut().as_mut() }; 
 
            // update the node
            node.update(children);
        }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CalcNode::update` function does not actually need access to its children - really it just wants the value that is calculated from them, so you can move the calculation out of the `update` function to prevent aliasing references:

```
fn update(&mut self, child_input: i64) {
    self.output = self.internal * child_input;
    self.internal += 1
}
```

```
// <-- Main loop
for &n in node_stack.iter().rev() {
    // collect updated children when available
    let children: Vec<&dyn CalcNode> = {
        n.children(arena)
            .map(|f| arena.get(f).unwrap().get().as_ref())
            .collect()
    };
    //example for n possible update funciton
    let child_input: i64 = children.iter().map(|&f| f.output()).sum();

    //get the node to update
    let node = { arena.get_mut(n).unwrap().get_mut().as_mut() };
    node.update(child_input);
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, I tried to simplify my example. In the full version of my application the output of the nodes is an wgpu::TextureView, which can't be copied.

Comment: @OliverWalter It's difficult for me to suggest anything concrete without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You could potentially make output return a reference and compute the update function using that reference.

Comment: I must correct myself, your answer still helped. Only moving out the collection of the outputs, and giving the update function an Vec of the collected outputs is the solution for me!
should I submit my code as an answer? Sry is my first post here.